# calling Array.prototype.reverse() on empty array?

Tags: javascript

Note: the code in this question was run in Chrome Console.

I encountered this problem when I was doing the [JS-puzzler](http://javascript-puzzlers.herokuapp.com/), question 21 (well.. it didn't gave a ordering though). The question ask about the result of:

```
var x = [].reverse; x();
```

and the answer is `window`. As the answer states:

> [].reverse will return this and when invoked without an explicit receiver object it will default to the default this AKA window.

Based on this understanding, I wrote a bit of code to test:

```
function Bar(){
  var x = [].reverse;
  console.log(x());
}
new Bar();
```

And guess what.. this code raise an error:

> TypeError: Array.prototype.reverse called on null or undefined

I want to ask why the x() called in the `new Bar` is not showing the `this` object, but raising exception instead?

Comment: Even `var x = [].reverse; x();` throws the same error. I don't know why it was `window` for you :(

Comment: @thefourtheye: sorry forgot to mention.. the code above was run in Chrome Console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call a function as in `x()`, the `this` pointer will be set to either `window` or `undefined` (in strict mode).  It is the method of calling the function that determines that value of `this`.

The methods of calling that let you control the value of `this` are:

```
x.call(xxx)
x.apply(xxx)
foo.x()
```

Calling as just:

```
x()
```

will set `this` to the default value which is `window` in normal JS mode or`undefined` in strict mode.

The other thing you may want to understand is that once you do:

```
var x = [].reverse;
```

Then, `x` only holds a reference to the `reverse()` function.  There is no association at all with the `[]` that you originally used.  So, when you call `x()`, you're just calling the `reverse()` function with no object association and thus `this` gets set to the default value which is `window` in normal JS mode or `undefined` in JS strict mode.

Comment: You mean to say, in strict mode `undefined` will be used? I tried this on Node.js and got the same error for `var x = [].reverse; x();`. I havn't even put `"use strict";`

Comment: @thefourtheye - yes.  In strict mode, `this` is set to `undefined` if called as `x()`.

Comment: @thefourtheye - in this case, it doesn't really matter whether you're in strict mode or not because `x()` isn't going to work either way (it will fail differently, but still fail either way).  You need to be associating the method with an array object.  I don't know what you're trying to do, but you either need to do `array.reverse()` or something like `x.call(array)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're getting a function reference without the scope it executes on. The `reverse` function, in its source, references `this`. If you call a function properly:

```
var obj = {
    run: function() { console.log(this) }
};

obj.run(); // this will be obj, as expected
```

But if you call it like this:

```
var broken = obj.run;
broken(); // this will be the global object
```

It's just the way javascript execution works in regards to scope. Calling a function with dot notation on an object will make `this` the object it's on.

If you're in a modern browser, you can `bind` the value of `this` to the right thing:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
var boundReverse = arr.reverse.bind( arr );

boundReverse() // [3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The original question is about the output of the following code.

```
var x = [].reverse;
x();
```

But the output of the snippet above is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.reverse called on null or undefined
```

Actually the equivalent call as follow gives the same error:

```
Array.prototype.reverse.call();
```

So, The answer of the question on [JavaScript Puzzler](http://javascript-puzzlers.herokuapp.com/) is not correct. Though the `Array.prototype.reverse` return `this`, the snippet will still throw an error, caused by lacking of an associating object.

This question can be used to test, if the tested one did understand the function definition via `var`, in which the `var` only holds the methods and drops the associating object.

Solution: (bind the associating object by calling)

```
// An associated object can be bound as below.
   var x = [].reverse;
   x.bind([1,2,3])();
// output : [3,2,1]
// equivalent to 
   Array.prototype.reverse.call([1,2,3]);
```